# What is this action called while you are putting on your shoes?

Tags: verbs, phrase-request

How do you describe this step of putting on shoes? Suppose you want to teach a kid how to wear their shoes.

> "...and then ____."

Can I say:

"and then pull up the heels"?

PS:

Some people (specially men) use a special tool for easing this action too (3rd picture).

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You generally use a shoehorn   ***to slide the heel of your foot into a shoe***

[Shoehorn](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/shoehorn):

> - A tool used to assist putting the foot into a shoe by sliding the heel in.

(Wiktionary)

Comment: Interesting! We say "to pull up the hill (of the shoes)" and you refer to  the opposite action:"to slide the heel (of your foot) in"! Thanks, @Josh61. Happy to learn "shoehorn" too. :)

Comment: shoehorn is also a verb. you can shoehorn something into place.

Comment: @dbliss - very true. Bizarrely I'm not sure I'd use it for shoes though! "I shoehorned on my shoes" sounds weird, probably because of the repeated "shoe".

Comment: @AndyT i agree! was thinking that when i posted. the verb, i think, tends to be used figuratively: e.g., maybe, "we managed to shoehorn a sick fight scene into that rom com script."